# Dimension error when specifying validation data in model.fit()

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have two different inputs. One input is 100 matrices of size 200x6000 which I give to a convolution neural network and the other one consists of 100 vectors of length 6000 which I give to a fully connected neural network. I concatenate these two networks which is then followed by a fully connected neural network.

Problem arises when I explicitly specify the validation data instead of using validation_split=0.2. And it then gives me following error:

[image]

My input to convolution neural network is image_train of dimensions (100,1,200,6000). Dimensions of input to fully connected neural network is (100,6000). And for validation the data image_valid is of dimension (30,1,200,6000) and dimension of positions_valid (30,6000).

Dimensions of Ytest for training data is (100,2) and Yvalid is (30,2)

My code is as follows:

```
###Setting up the architecture

###Convolution neural network
i1 = Input(shape=(1, 200, 6000))

c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first')(i1)
c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(c1)
c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
#c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(c1)
#c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = Flatten()(c1)

###Fully connected neural network
i2 = Input(shape=(6000, ))
c2 = Dense(64, input_shape = (6000,), activation='relu')(i2)
#c2 = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(c2)
#c2 = Dense(64, input_shape = (4500,), activation='relu')(i2)
c2 = Dropout(0.2)(c2)

###Concatenating
c = concatenate([c1, c2])

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(c)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([i1, i2], [output])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='sgd',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit([image_train, positions_train], Ytest, batch_size=32,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=([image_valid, positions_valid], Yvalid))
```

If I used validation_split = 0.2, the same code would work. But I want to specify validation_data and when I do it gives the error that I mentioned above. Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Error occurs because of inappropriate dims size in validation, a quick check, use same training data as validation. The info you given, it should work perfectly.

Comment: The only thing that changes is the number of examples in validation and training data. Otherwise, its the same. I thought that it's not necessary to have same number of training examples and validation examples?

Comment: That was just for conformation that validation data (in fit function) doesn't create any problem. Anyway, i think, little more info about problem, can give better guess/ idea to community.